# angular toggle between templates using their url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I need to find a way to toggle between views on a single page using angular. I already created it using routes, but that's not the best practice for my app.

What I need is the way in angular to switch between these views that are in separate html files without changing routes, maybe working with ngShow/Hide or something similar. I'm pretty new to angular so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at ng-include -- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: ng-inlcude did the trick, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

ng-include did the trick. I just needed to set paths properly.